# Чем отличаются подключенные шрифты?

Tags: css, шрифты

Подключаю шрифт `font-family: Gotham` и пишу `font-style normal и font-weight normal`.

Подключаю другой шрифт  `font-family: Gotham` и пишу `font-style normal и font-weight: bold`.

Вопрос...

Чем отличается первый шрифт от второго. Я понимаю, что один нормальный, а второй болт,  но разве, к примеру , если я буду писать,

```
p{
  font-family:Gotham;
  font-weight:bold;
}
```

он же должен взять шрифт переделать в болт и тогда зачем я подключал этот `Gotham` и делал его `bold` еще во время подключение? Или же он возьмет `sans-serif` и переделает в болт?

Comment: Ничего не понял...  `Gotham` - Это название шрифта... А `sans-serif` - Это тип... О чем вообще вопрос? Ничего не понятно

Comment: подключаю один шрифт Gotham только один болд , а другой нормальный. Зачем его дважды так подключать ?, если можно указать только нормальный и потом уже при указании стилей указать bold

Comment: Так это два разных....

Comment: Если автор шрифта решил, что его `произведение искусства`  должно быть тоненьким и изящным...  То пиши, не пиши `font-weight: bold` жирным оно не будет

Comment: просто один файл  Gotham Bold.ttf а другой Gotham.ttf и вот один болд, другой нормальный. но просто я бы мог подключить просто Gotham.ttf и потом уже в css стилях к параграфу написать font-weight bold...и всё должно стать жирным(становится) но вот зачем подключать надо файл с болт я не понимаю...

Comment: Ну сказали же уже, не будет оно жирным. Это тут не работает, как в том же фотошопе. Указываешь только normal - на любой размер от 100 до 900 будет всегда тонкий шрифт (если шрифт не поддерживает несколько размеров одновременно). Подключаешь для bold шрифт, то будет подтягиваться для bold уже другой шрифт, не тонкий.